# Is this proof about composition functions correct?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

For this to work i did draw diagrams and i came up with example of functions.

Let F be the sets of all functions from the set of integers to set of integers. Prove or disapprove:

FALSE

$\forall  f,g,h \in F$ if $ f\circ h = g \circ h$ then $f=g$

Now, i prove the negation is true.
Let $f,g,h$ be the functions from set of integers to set of integers defined as

$f=\{(3,1),(4,2),(5,2)\}$

$g=\{(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)\}$

$h=\{(1,3),(2,5)\}$

$ f\circ h = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

$g \circ h = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

We see that $ f\circ h = g \circ h$ . Also, $f\not= g$ because 
$\{(3,1),(4,2),(5,2)\} \not= \{(3,2),(4,2),(5,1)\} $ .

In other words, for input in function $f$ there is an output that has to be equal for function $g$ if the input given is that of $f$.

Comment: Just produce a counterexample to disprove something of the form "for all ..."

Comment: Is my example ok? To make up functions and represent them as set?

Comment: But $g \circ h$  is computed incorrectly. $g \circ h = \{(1,2),(2,1)\} \neq f \circ h = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$

Comment: Oops i see. But otherwise, lets say this was correct, is this kind of counterexample valid?

Comment: I totally messed up the numbers, but it's just the idea that im interested in.

Comment: Yes, think simple. Take $h$ to be a constant function, eg. $h$ identically $0$. Now produce functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f$ and $g$ take same value at $0$, but different at atleast some other integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f=\{(0,7),(1,4)\}$

$g=\{(0,7),(1,5)\}$

$h \equiv 0$ disproves.